# Script improvement suggestions

Tags: macos, bash, shell

The following script is used to check SMART status for any drive(s) on a Macintosh.

It works nicely, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to first list, then cycle through all the results from `diskutil list | grep /dev/` as that command will always list all the connected devices, and thus makes the script portable.

Is there a better way to do this without first outputting to the $DISKLIST log file? Other suggestions are welcome, too!

```
# Check SMART status

DISKLIST=`mktemp -t DISK-XXXXX.log`

diskutil list | grep /dev/ > $DISKLIST

for i in  `cat $DISKLIST` ;

do

STATUS=$(diskutil info $i | awk -F': *' '/SMART/{print $2}')

if [ "$STATUS" = "Verified" ]; then
        echo "SMART Status OK for disk $i" 
else

        echo "** SMART Status $STATUS for disk $i **" 
fi

done

rm $DISKLIST
```

As an example, these are typical results from the key command in the script:

```
$ diskutil list | grep /dev/
/dev/disk0
/dev/disk1
/dev/disk2
/dev/disk3
/dev/disk4
/dev/disk5
/dev/disk6
/dev/disk7
/dev/disk8
```

Comment: Try the codereview site. We're here to help fix problems, not critique/improve code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use command substitution so:

```
for i in $(diskutil list | grep /dev/)
do 
....
```

The output of the command is directly substituted in the for loop and no DISKLIST file is needed. More on this on [abs:command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)